# how to use different template for each of the views inside controller in Kohana 3?

Tags: templates, controller, kohana-3

i've got one template controler (ex. Controller_DefaultTemplate )and others (ex. Controller_Admin) are extending it. In tutiorials (ex. here http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2009/12/30/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-3/) they do like this in Controller_DefaultTemplate:

`public $template = 'admin/index';`

but i need different views for different actions inside

```
    class Controller_Admin extends Controller_DefaultTemplate {
    function action_material(){ 
        $template = 'admin/material';
}
    function action_newsedit(){ 
        $template = 'admin/newsedit';
}
```

... and so on,
is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to set View's filename with `set_filename()` method. Using zombor's style you will lose all variables that were set for `$this->template`.

```
public function action_newsedit()
{
    // note that $this->template is already View object as we are in Controller_Template
    $this->template->set_filename('admin/newsedit');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, like so:

```
public function action_newsedit()
{
    $this->template = new View('admin/newsedit');
}
```

The template is created in the constructor of the controller, so you simply need to overwrite it in your action.

Comment: in both cases i get `Kohana_View_Exception [ 0 ]: The requested view template could not be found` error

Comment: You need a default template existing already (before() still needs to run and make the template file). In the default case, it's views/template.php

Answer (score 0):

A template is a wrapper for all your views. Inside the template you would have `<?php echo $content; ?>` and then in the action you would simply call your view to be placed inside of that template. `$this->template->content = View::factory('page');` As I understand it, thats how its meant to work.